# Webpack 4 how to get correct font path

Tags: webpack, font-awesome

I am using webpack 4 to generate and separate my app resource files, basically this is what I want : 
[image]

But I am using font-awesome and some font-awesome class use font files so I have 404 errors for font files : 
[image]

So how do I get this working? Here is an extract of my webpack config :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {app: `./index.js`},
  output: {
    filename: './js/[name].[hash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: './css/[name].[hash].css',
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss?$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [
                require('autoprefixer')
              ]
            }
          },
          'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally here is how I solved my problem :

```
{
  test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
    publicPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
      return url.indexOf('fa-') >= 0 ? `../${url}` : url;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hello brother, i have an issue regarding my fonts files, kindly tell me what should i put in resourcePath and context ?

Comment: Hi @zeeshanzahoor `resourcePath` and `context` are parameters of `publicPath` it is not you who give a value to this parameters, their values are given by the loader `file-loader`. See the documentation here https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#publicpath

Comment: Hello @Moussa 
i am using webpack 4 in my project 
Everything is working fne. but some of my files (material design icons) are making issue in build.
when i comment these files.
Webpack make build successfully. But when i uncomment/use that files i got the error of module not found, Even the file and paths are correct, i don't know how to solve it. Kindly help me if u  can, Here is link for my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72196123/how-to-include-icons-and-fonts-file-in-webpack-4-in-react